# BigQuery: Cannot read field 'stamp' of type TIMESTAMP_MICROS as DATETIME

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm playing with BigQuery's Standard SQL [Wildcard Table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference) functionality.

I have a table with the following schema:

```
_PARTITIONTIME  TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
stamp           TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
value           FLOAT       NULLABLE
source          STRING      NULLABLE
...
```

Because the tables in my dataset have mixed schemas and their names are not commonly prefixed, I intend on making a wide Wildcard match - then, narrowing `_TABLE_SUFFIX` in the `WHERE`:

```sql
SELECT
*,
_TABLE_SUFFIX AS table_name
FROM `my-project.my-dataset.*`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r"cars")
```

This is as-basic as I can make it. `cars` only matches a single table. 
I intend on adding additional tables to the REGEX above. e.g: `cars|trucks|...`

When I execute the above query, I get the following error:

`Cannot read field 'stamp' of type TIMESTAMP_MICROS as DATETIME`

Furthermore, when I attempt to remove the `stamp` from my `SELECT` and use the `source` column in it's place:

```sql
SELECT
source,
_TABLE_SUFFIX AS table_name
FROM `my-project.my-dataset.*`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r"cars")
```

BigQuery now tells me: `Unrecognized name: source at [2:1]`

What's happening here in both cases? Why does BigQuery want to cast my `stamp` column, and why is it unable to find `source` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What's happening here in both cases? Why does BigQuery want to cast my stamp column, and why is it unable to find source ?

In order to execute a standard SQL query that uses a wildcard table, BigQuery automatically infers the schema for that table. BigQuery uses the schema for the most recently created table that matches the wildcard as the schema for the wildcard table. If the schema is inconsistent across tables matched by the wildcard table, BigQuery returns an error.

This explains both case you see!

In first case - the most recent table has _PARTITIONTIME as DATETIME data type
In second case - same most recent table just simply does not have `source` field in it

Comment: What's a solution to this? I have daily partitions from 2017-2020. But there's a couple of months in 2017 where a column is defined as `STRING`. Everywhere else it's `DATETIME`.