# BigQuery - mixed schema: Cannot read field of type STRING as DATETIME

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a daily partitioned table spanning across multiple years. One of the columns is defined as `DATETIME` 90% of the time, but there is a small, continuous range of a dates in the middle where that column is defined as `STRING`. The value of the columns are always formatted as `2017-07-11T05:43:05.[\d+Z?]`.

When trying to select across all those dates using a wildcard, I get the error:

```
Cannot read field of type STRING as DATETIME
```

I understand the [reason this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47645534/774907), so attempting to cast the column and juggle types doesn't work.

## Question

Is there a solution to this short of extracting that data out of BigQuery and re-uploading it with the schema corrected?

Comment: Write an  `UPDATE` statement to fix them.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction? According to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#changing_a_columns_data_type you can't change the column type.

Comment: You can't update existing table but you can create a new one using CREATE TABLE `tablename` AS SELECT .... statement

Comment: Is this really a partitioned table, or multiple tables with a date in the name for each one?